# Count of dates monthly and yearly. Cumulative (or Running Total) count of non blank dates monthly and yearly

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to get count of dates with respect to  month and year for non blanks for a date column.

Second I want to have like cumulative for all the months and years (should not start cumulative again after the year should be for all the months and all the years as shown in pictures.

[image]

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

the `count()` function already ignores null values when applied to a column. For the cumulative count, if you have SQL 2012 or more recent, you can add an `over` clause to it. More details on the `over` clause in BOL: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-over-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Can you apply in my query please

Comment: You provided no query.

Comment: SELECT
[Catgory],
[Category2],
[1] AS Jan18,
 [2] AS Feb18,
[3] AS Mrz18,
 [4] AS Apr18,
  [5] AS Mai18,
FROM
(Select 

[Catgory],
[Category2],
 MONTH([Workdatemorning]) as TMonth
  from
    [dbo].[MainOutputSQL]
 where Year([workdatemorningl]) = 2018 

 ) source
 PIVOT
(COUNT([category])
    FOR TMonth
    IN ( [1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9], [10], [11], [12] )
)AS pvtMonth
  order by [category]

Comment: I am not sure about field [WorkdateMonday], as i am new to sql